# Why does unity trigger wrong index Quality setting of anti-aliasing using dropdown UI Element?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making runtime UI for quality settings  in Unity so players can edit settings, I have a dropdown for selecting `anti-aliasing` quality index. The dropdown options are in a sync with the available options in
main quality settings in editor, for some reason, when choosing option from the drop down, a wrong index of `anti-aliasing` is triggered.

C# Function that is assigned to dropdown value change is as below

```
    public void SetAntiAliasing(int aaIndex)
    {
        QualitySettings.antiAliasing = aaIndex;
      
    }
```

This is how the dropdown UI element is configured
[image: This is how the dropdown UI element is configured]

This is the anti-aliasing config in editor
[image: This is the anti-aliasing config in editor]

Comment: And what values do you receive in that function?

Comment: @UnholySheep  The function dynamically receives the index of selected option in the drowp-down UI and  is "supposed" to  apply that index in the anti-aliasing options and activate the target option.

Comment: So you are receiving a `1` when you select `2x Multi Sampling`? Because that is not the value you should be setting on `QualitySettings.antiAliasing` (as per the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-antiAliasing.html)

Comment: Ohh I see, So Function should Do  index  + 1??

Comment: It  does not work by adding 1 or 2 or keeping it default indexed either

Comment: How did you get `+ 1`? Supported values are 0, 2, 4 and 8

Comment: I got it now, You are right. So When I add 2 with index, the result is correct upto 4X but stops at 8, I have do use the sqaure of Index

Comment: The way it works is  `index * index`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249511/discussion-between-wajid-and-unholysheep).